# Site Collection Allwebs for current user

Tags: 2013, development, permissions, site-collection, web

I need to iterate to all the web of a site collection using the current user permission. 
I tried:

```
foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
{
 if (!(web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.Open))) continue;
}
```

But it is not working. 
I got an error on site.AllWebs

I need all the sites (and subsites) of the site collection. (all the siblings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1. `SPWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser` method

[SPWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478651.aspx) gets the subsites **beneath the current site of which the current user is a member**

Since it retrieves only **beneath the current site(1 level only)**, you could use the following method to return **all web sites that are contained within the site collection**:

```
private static void GetAllSubwebsForCurrentUser(SPWeb currentWeb, ICollection<SPWeb> allWebs)
{
     allWebs.Add(currentWeb);
     var webs = currentWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser();
     foreach (SPWeb web in webs)
     {
         if (web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser().Count > 0)
         {
            GetAllSubwebsForCurrentUser(web, allWebs);
         }
         else
         {
             allWebs.Add(web);
         }
     }
 }
```

Usage

```
using (var site = new SPSite("http://contoso.intranet.com"))
{
    var allWebs = new Collection<SPWeb>();
    GetAllSubwebsForCurrentUser(site.RootWeb, allWebs);
    foreach (SPWeb web in allWebs)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Web site:{0} ({1})", web.Title, web.Url);
         web.Dispose();
    }
}
```

### Option 2. `SPSite.AllWebs` property

Use [SPSite.AllWebs property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.allwebs.aspx) to Gets the collection of **all Web sites that are contained within the site collection**, including the top-level site and its subsites:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
            {
                using (var site = new SPSite("http://contoso.intranet.com"))
                {
                    var allWebs = site.AllWebs;
                    foreach (SPWeb web in allWebs)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Web site:{0} ({1})", web.Title, web.Url);
                        web.Dispose();
                    }
                }          
            });
```

Comment: Please check the answer a little bit carefully, in option 1 you will find the GetAllSubwebsForCurrentUser method that returns ALL web sites for a user that are contained within the site collection

Comment: It returns all the web in the same hierarchy of the current web (all parents and children). But what about siblings?

Comment: It returns all the webs within site collection where user has enough permissions, it traverses starting from ROOT web across the all sites within site collection. I dont get about siblings, you mean web sites from different site collections?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following :

```
    using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://example/site/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPWebCollection webCollection = web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser();
    }
}
```

This will give you the list of all webs for current user.

Comment: but in which site collection?

Comment: Check the edited post.

Comment: but I ll get only the sub site of the current Web, but not all the other sites in the site collection

Comment: You will get all sites under the site collection. Try this

Comment: No, I just get the subsite of the current web

Comment: How many is expected?

Comment: I have to iterate all the web sites (including sub sites) of the site collection

Comment: You can again use web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser() on the subsite

Comment: but I wont get the siblings, just the children

Comment: The method SPWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser returns subsites beneath the current site (1 level), please see my answer for details